# How to open aar file , put changes and save it

Tags: android, android-studio

i have library lib.aar . I know its just a zip file. I need change there little layout settings. But i never work with this file. Can any good guy explaine me how i can open aar file - put changes to layout - and save , after using as always as lib.aar ? please

Comment: Doing that is neither recommended not straight forward. You can't just edit resource files once they are compiled. During compilation resource files are transformed into a binary format. Why can't you just change the source code of the library and then compile it again? If you can't do that for whatever reason then your obit option is to decompile the library with a decompiler then change the source code and compile it again.

Comment: i think that is impossible or you get very painful to decompile and compile after edit something

Comment: @XaverKapeller man, can u tell me some decompiler? i just dont have access to source of aar file. So i have only this way. It's not hack ), im not stolen something. Its just my task.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Modifying contents of Android .aar file / Converting to and from .zip format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38860912/modifying-contents-of-android-aar-file-converting-to-and-from-zip-format)