# Gradle excluding a .jar library

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, timber-android

I have a library say abc.aar, this includes timber.jar in its lib. This timber is Version - 2.5.1
Library abc is developed by a different team, and I cannot modify that. :-(
I am developing another library which has a dependency on abc.aar.
I need to use timber-4.7.0.
How do I exclude timber2.5.1 from compiling.
I tried the following

```
    compile(name: 'abc-aaa', ext: 'aar'){
           exclude module: 'com.jakewharton.timber'
    }
compile 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.7.0'
```

This did not work for me. I get the Timber reference from abc module. (timber-2.5.1). Any help much appreciated.

Comment: You wil have to rebuild the whole library

Comment: @H.Brooks Thanks for the quick reply. Here library abc is developed by a different team, and I cannot modify that.

Comment: Why can't you modify it? Your best bet is to send the developer of the library a email

Comment: `aar` is a ZIP archive which can be unzipped, get it's contents modified like removing the timber jar from it and zip it again. Checkout this link: https://stackoverflow.com/q/38860912/2949966. Beware that doing this might break certain functionalities in your `abc-aaa` library do to the difference in versions but it's worth a shot.

Comment: As a side note, gradle cannot manage dependencies within packaged libraries since it depends on certain files like `pom.xml` which is usually not packaged in `aar` libraries.