# How to exclude .jar file from .aar file

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, dependencies, gson, dynamic-feature

Is there a way to exclude .jar file from .aar file. My project is not running as I have one module that contains a .aar file in which Gson.jar is used as a library and I need it in my main app as well so I need to implement Gson dependency also. When I tried to run my project I got multidex error:

Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithBundleMultiDexListForDevelopmentBuildDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: Error while generating the main dex list.

Please help me to solve this issue. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Finally after a lot of searching I have found solution.

Solution that worked for me:

```html
$ unzip myLib.aar -d tempFolder # or other extracting tool
# Change whatever you need
$ jar cvf myNewLib.aar -C tempFolder/ .
```

Reference link: [Modifying contents of Android .aar file / Converting to and from .zip format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38860912/modifying-contents-of-android-aar-file-converting-to-and-from-zip-format)

Answer (score 0):

You can have exculde in the targets 
 just like this

```
 sourceSets.main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src']
        aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
        renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        java {
            exclude '**/VanillaARMv*'
            exclude '**/VanillaX86*'
        }
        resources {
            exclude '**/VanillaARMv*'
            exclude '**/VanillaX86*'
        }
        aidl {
            exclude '**/VanillaARMv*'
            exclude '**/VanillaX86*'
        }
        renderscript {
            exclude '**/VanillaARMv*'
            exclude '**/VanillaX86*'
        }

    }
```

Here i am excluding whatever i have in VanillaARMv* and in VanillaX86* folders from the target build.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. I don't understand the  above script please do let know how can I exclude the Gson library from my module. I have two flavors in my app named as <productionBuild> & <developmentBuild>. Looking forward to get positive response. Thanks

Comment: If you can post your build.gradle, i can try to add the exclude property