# Error android:exported in Console GooglePlay - Android 12

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, android-12

I have this problem when i´m try send the archive .aab in console google play. I watch many videos, but i can´t resolve this problem.

I did my project in Ionic and Cordova.

[erro in console googleplay](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Y776.png)

In AndroidManifest, I set android:exported in  and in , but after that, in MergedManifest show a error with , I don't know what i need to do, because in my AndroidManifest the  dont exist. How I solve this problem?

```
Error: android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for <receiver>. Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details.
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RylUT.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iCNTr.png)

Comment: Do you have a third party SDK with AAR file? Maybe it's like this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73511208

Comment: is that? thanks for your response friend!

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this in the `config.xml`

```
<edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application/receiver">
            <receiver android:exported="true" />
        </edit-config>
```